# bind:this referencing the same variable between components

Tags: svelte

See example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-wave-j0kp2?file=/App.svelte

I have one component that uploads an image and displays it. However, when uploading an image in several different instances of this component, the image will always be displayed in the first component.

I want to be able to upload and display the image in different invidivual components.

I'm using `bind:this` to set a reference to the `<img>` tag, so I can render the image. But it seems that all of the different instances of the component is referencing the same img tag?

What is happening here and how should I go about implementing it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your images outside of Image-component (for ex. App.svelte or store) and feed correct image as a prop to each Image-component

```
<Image src={image1} />
<Image src={image2} />
```

Now the Image components are the same, therefore a strange behaviour

EDIT:

Actually your code should work. Here is a very simple example with input-fields:
https://svelte.dev/repl/8d364486b1c64d47aa0a03fd50d767bf?version=3.24.1

I don’t know why your code doesn’t work, but if you save your images to an array outside, then it should work.

EDIT2:

I have updated my REPL, now it works. With ipad I couldn’t get onload-event working with image load, but `createObjectURL` made the trick. My example works, but I don’t know what’s the mistake in your example. It should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I guess it's still a mystery why the original code doesn't work ... 
Well at least I have an alternative now.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it working. It seems like it isn't related to the "addImage" function. It's something about the html I'm using. Thing is, I need to use the tags like this in order to hide the input element and so forth ...
Looks like it has something to do with the label I'm using. If I don't use the label and don't hide the input, then it works. But I don't want to show the input button ... I want the image area to act as the button.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue seems to be the "input" element being outside the "label" element. If I put it inside, it works.

It's strange, because it should work either way...

EDIT: The reason for this is apparently because the original solution depends on ID's, and Svelte doesn't automatically scope ID's.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Maybe you should make as simple as possible example and open an issue in svelte’s github pages.

Comment: Apparently not a bug, see:

https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5297

ID's aren't scoped, so in the original code there will be duplicate ID's.

Comment: Sorry I missed totally ’for=””’ attribute, while I was simplifying your code (and Ipad is not a good choice for this kind of work). Anyway I got your example working by: define variable `let inp`, remove `for` attribute, add `bind:this={inp}` to `<input/>` tag and finally add `on:click={()=>inp.click()}` to your `<label>` tag

Comment: By the way is there any reason you can’t move the `<input>` tag inside the `<label> </label>` container? Then you can remove `for` attribute and everything works (as you mentioned earlier). I didn’t find any problem with this approach and I think it’s the simplest solution.

Comment: And one more idea... You can ”scope” your id like this: define a variable `let id = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)` , in label-element `for=”image-load{id}”` and finally with input-element `id=”image-load{id}”`

Comment: @grohjy I've moved the <input> tag inside the <label>, yes, so it's working fine. I was just curious before why it wasn't working the other way.

Interesting ideas with scoping the ID, might come in handy some time. Although for now, not using the "for" attribute seems like the best strategy :)

Comment: It was interesting problem to examine, I did learn many things.